# Dynamically setting type or result from invoked generic method?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

My apologies if the question is somewhat unclear;  I'm not entirely certain how to phrase this.

My issue is this.  I have two classes, `Manager<T>` and `Result<T>`.  Within `Manager<T>`, I have a whole raft of retrieval functions.  Ordinarily, I would call `Manager<T>` and set its type like so:

```
Manager<SpecialDataType> mgr = new Manager<SpecialDataType>;
```

After which I set up my Result type, and fill it with my function from Manager, where 1 is a parameter for the GetItem function shown.  I can then access things in my item:

```
Result<SpecialDataType> item = new Result<SpecialDataType>;
item = mgr.GetItem(1);
string x = item.Teaser;
```

OK.  So now, what I'm trying to do is set the `<SpecificDataType>` to be filled in at run time.  I think I've got half of the solution already, using generic types, like so:

```
Type generalType= Type.GetType("SpecificDataType");
Type managerType= typeof(Manager<>).MakeGenericType(generalType);
var managerInstance= Activator.CreateInstance(managerType);
object[] args = {1};
MethodInfo getItemMethod = managerInstance.GetMethod("GetItem");
```

But here's where I get stuck. There are specific properties that my Result class has that I need to be able to access.  They are, or course, set by the data type I'm casting into.  When I do an `Invoke`, like so:

```
var item = getItemMethod.Invoke(managerInstance, args);
```

I'm not getting any of my properties that I know are part of `item`.  That makes sense, I suppose, because we don't know what `item` is.  So, we tried this:

```
Type dataType = typeof(SmartFormData<>).MakeGenericType(sfType);
var item = Activator.CreateInstance(dataType);
item = getItemMethod.Invoke(managerInstance, args);
```

And got the same result.  I can't seem to get to `item.Teaser`.

I'm not a c# coder natively (as though that's not apparent already from this overly complicated question I'm asking), so I'm not incredibly familiar with reflection and generic types.  Can anyone point me in the right direction for how to solve this problem, or how to approach it from a different angle?  The only caveat is that I cannot modify the `Manager<T>` and `Result<T>` functions;  I have to use what I'm given there.

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

Comment: You have to use reflection to access the members of `item` as well, or cast it to the expected type.

Comment: Ah, but the problem at hand is that I can't cast to the expected type, since I don't know what that is to start with.  All I have is that `"SpecificDataType"` string. Reflection it is, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Dark Falcon correctly notes in his comment you will have to use reflection to get the members of your item.

Or, if you are in .NET 4 or above, you can use the `dynamic` keyword to greatly simplify things:

```
Type generalType= Type.GetType("SpecificDataType");
Type managerType= typeof(Manager<>).MakeGenericType(generalType);
dynamic managerInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(managerType);
var item = managerInstance.GetItem(1);
string x = item.Teaser;
```

Comment: This compiled, but didn't actually return any information at all.  That might be on my end of things;  `dynamic` seems like it'd be the right solution here, but it doesn't seem to work for what I'm wanting to do.

Comment: Sorry.  I'm unable to pull item.Teaser into string x.  It simply returns null, though I know data is present, and I can access it if I do all my calls with traditional data typing.

Comment: @MattDempster: I am certain that the exact item you are getting actually has a `Teaser` that is `null`. If it would be a problem with the dynamic binding you would get an exception and not `null`. So most likely, the problem is that you are either supplying the wrong parameter to `GetItem` or you are creating an instance for the wrong `SpecificDataType`. Try to use static typing with the exact `SpecificDataType` you use when you not get a result. I am sure `item.Teaser` also returns `null`.

Comment: Code to test: `var managerInstance = new Manager<SpecificDataType>(); var item = managerInstance.GetItem(1); var x = item.Teaser;`

Comment: I figured it out, @DanielHilgarth.  In my specific case, I needed to use `dynamic item` and generate another Activator instance.  It turned out that the data type I was trying to access in the first place was ALSO a class based on a generic.  Thanks for steering me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the invocation result to the type you're expecting

```
var item = (Result<SpecificDataType>)getItemMethod.Invoke(managerInstance, args);
```